# How to exit application when network isn't reachable using Monotouch?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

How to exit application when network isn't reachable using Monotouch?

Comment: Do you mean immediately on startup? Or do you mean, a user has been using your app for 10 minutes, they momentarily lose connectivity, and you destroy their work?

Answer (score 0):

This is against Apple's guidelines, and is likely to lead to your application being rejected. However, if this is an in-house application only, you can throw an exception that is not handled anywhere (create your own custom exception type that gets bubbled all the way up). This will not be a graceful exit, but it will close the application.

I read that you can send a Sigabort message, but I'm unsure how to do that from within MonoTouch.